# Counting the number of words from a file

Tags: c#, file

A word in this context is defined is a letter or a number. However, something like \n is not considered a word.

Below in my code I am trying to count the number of words in a file but at the for loop's local variable declaration I get the error `Null Reference exception`.

I am not sure why I get this error. I get the variable Line equal to null which shouldn't happen because the text file DOES have one word "hello world" in it..

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
while (sr.ReadLine()!=null)
{
    Line =sr.ReadLine();
    for (**int i = 1**; i < (Line.Length+1); i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(Line[i]) == true && Char.IsLetterOrDigit(Line[i - 1]) == true)
        {
            if (LetterRecent == false)
            {
               wordCount = wordCount + 1;
            }
            LetterRecent = true;
        }
        else
        {
             LetterRecent = false;
        }
    }
}

sr.Close();
```

Comment: I would check your loop indexes

Comment: Are you sure it's at the index declaration and not at Line.Length? In your while condition you're checking if sr.Readline() isn't null but then you're reading another line again right away and it might be at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discarding half of the lines in the file by calling sr.ReadLine() twice. If you read the last line of the file in the while statement, the call to Line.Length will throw the null reference exception.

Try something this:

```
var wordCount = 0;
var line = sr.ReadLine();
while( line != null ) {
  for( var i = 1; i < line.Length; i++ ) {
    // Count words
  }
  line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This is the same solution I got after I followed @reins observation of ReadLine() being called twice.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing ReadLine() twice for each line.

You could do something like:

```
count = 0;
while (line = sr.ReadLine()) {
  char oldChar = 0;
  for (char c in line) {
    if (c != oldChar && Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) count++;
    oldChar = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: that might be the reason because I only have one word in the textfile which is "hello world" how can I make this work without ReadLine() being called twice?

Comment: @SdfsdSdf, "hello world" is 2 words not one.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 sorry that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `wordCount` before using it.

```
Int wordCount = 0;
while (sr.ReadLine()!=null)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your loop condition to be like this:

```
while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
{
    Line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```